# How to send indexpath when performing segue on collectionViewCell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, segue

I have a collection view controller with similar cells and I want each cell open next viewController with specific content. I think I must send indexpath.row with the segue but in this part I face an error:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let newViewController = segue.destination as?     myCollectionViewController {
        newViewController.passedValue = indexPath.row // exactly here
    }
}
```

Comment: `myCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems[0]`? (or something like that)

Comment: can't you use this delegate function didSelectRowAtIndexPath for your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code. `indexPath.row` variable is not declared in your `prepare` function. To pass the selected cell info to another view controller you first need to add a global variable in your class.

`var selectedCell = 0`

Next implement the function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in your class. This function is called every time you select a cell. In this function get the cell info and assign it to `selectedCell` var

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedCell = indexPath.row
    }
```

Now in your `prepare` method use this var value and pass it on to the next controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
            let VC = segue.destination as! YourViewController 
            VC.passed = selectedCell 
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code:

```
    newViewController.passedValue = indexPath.row // exactly here
```

what is the value of `indexPath` here? Is is an instance variable?

Instead of using `segue`, use `UICollectionViewDelegate` method:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    //Push your controller here
}
```

Comment: indexPath.row is adress of collectionViewCell.

Comment: The code you have written is in prepare(for:sender:) method. Here you don't have any local variable named indexPath. That's what I am asking. Is is an instance variable?